# R Manipulate Package

Tags: r, rstudio

Im trying to create a rather large menu using the manipulate package in R. My problem is that all the buttons are written underneath one another. Here is an example with only two buttons, does anyone know how to change it so that the buttons appear NEXT to one another? A different package that allows for more flexible button placement would be acceptable too.

```
#install.packages("UsingR")
library(manipulate)
library(UsingR)

data(galton)

########## Manipulable Histogram ##########

myHist <- function(mu, Color){
hist(galton$child, col=Color, breaks=10)
lines(c(mu,mu), c(0, 150), col="red", lwd=5)
}

manipulate(myHist(mu, Color), mu = slider(62, 74, step=.5),
       Color=picker("blue", "red", initial="blue"))
```

Comment: Have you looked at `shiny`? I think it would be fair to call it `manipulate`'s successor: http://shiny.rstudio.com/

Comment: Ooph, thats a whole level of complexity beyond what I was expecting. Ill take it though. Im not sure where I click to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer.

Have you looked at shiny? I think it would be fair to call it manipulate's successor: [shiny.rstudio.com](http://shiny.rstudio.com). You will find it *very* flexible, but hopefully still approachable!

Comment: Successfully implemented. Looks awesome.

Comment: Glad to hear it went well!